# In dplyr when summarising after filtering the row name is not showing up

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

For example in the mtcars datasets I want to get the car with the max HP and has 6 cyl and gears so I run the code and get the value but the name of the car isnt showing up, how do you I change that?

```
+ filter(cyl=="6" & gear=="4") %>% 
+ select(hp)
> v=mtcars %>% 
+ filter(cyl=="6" & gear=="4") %>% 
+ select(hp) %>% 
+ summarise(max(hp))
```

This is the result

```
> v
  max(hp)
1     123
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using base R functions with the help of `magrittr`'s pipe operator for readability.

```
library(magrittr)

mtcars %>%
  subset(cyl == 6 & gear == 4) %>%
  subset(hp == max(hp)) %>%
  rownames()

#[1] "Merc 280"  "Merc 280C"
```

Note that the max `hp` value is same for above two cars so it returns both the car names.

Answer (score 0):

We can create a column of rownames as the tidyverse would strip off the rownames attributes

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
   rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
   filter(cyl=="6" & gear=="4") %>% 
   select(rn, hp) %>% 
   slice(which.max(hp))
```

---

In this particular case, it is the `summarise` step removes the rownames.  According to `?summarise`

> Data frame attributes are not preserved, because summarise() fundamentally creates a new data frame.